# Difference between 且... 且... and 一面… 一面

Tags: grammar, syntax, literary-chinese

The structures 且+verb 且+verb and 一面… 一面... (or 一边... 一边...) are used to describe two actions taking place at the same time.

But I've only seen us 且... 且... used with monosyllabic verbs and no complements. Like: 且跑且喊, 且谈且走, etc.

While the two others can be used with verbs and complements , like: 我喜欢一边看书，一边喝茶。

So my question is: is it possible to use the 且... 且... structure just the same as 一面… 一面... or 一边... 一边..., or is it limited to monosyllabic verbs?

谢谢大家！

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they function similarly

[且 X 且 Y] is a classical literary structure, only used with monosyllabic verbs and no complements.

Example:  且戰且退

[一面 X 一面 Y] is  more colloquial and works with verbs or long verb phrases

Example:  一面戰鬥一面徹退

Comment: Thank you! This is what I deduced from what I saw but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The form, "且(A)... 且(B)...", represents a "set phrase (成語) that was often used in the literature to condense a long sentence/story into a 4 characters phrase. Yes, A and B are commonly limited to monosyllabic verbs.

Unlike "且(A)... 且(B)...", its equivalent, "(一)边...(一)边..." and "一面...一面..." do not have the "monosyllabic verb" restriction.

Comment: Thank you very much!